# How can I convert a batch of 30 text files to an Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 30 text files (trial balances) downloaded from accounting software and saved at a specific file path (say a folder).

I need to open these 30 text files one by one and convert them to Excel, and then each file needs to be saved as a separate worksheet in a new Excel workbook.

How can I do this?

Comment: Start by looking at using `Dir()` to loop over the files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The following like function will list out all the files from specified path. Filter it to .TXT/.CSV as you need.

```
Function getFilesFromPath(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim fileList     As Variant
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim obFile       As Object
    Dim obFSO        As Object
    Dim obFolder     As Object
    Dim obFiles      As Object

    Set obFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set obFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set obFiles = oFolder.Files

    If obFiles.Count = 0 Then 
       Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim fileList(1 To obFiles.Count)

    i = 1

    For Each obFile In obFiles
        fileList(i) = obFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    getFilesFromPath = fileList

End Function
```

Next step is to read file. Following code snippet will help you there.

```
myFile = "C:\MyFiles\file1.txt". ' myFile is a string variable

Open myFile For Input As #1. ' This opens the file for reading. "#1" is used as reference. You can open as many files as you want with #n.

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline ' text is a string variable
Loop
```

Following code will write the data in the worksheet

```
Range("A1").Value = text. ' This will write value of variable 'text' in cell A1.
```

Of course, depending on the data and your requirement, either you need to split the data in variable 'text' based on the separator or use Text to Column feature of MS-Excel. You'll need to merge these two code snippets together to get desired result.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try it.

I am a beginner, so to start with above codes, I would paste all code into the module,and then change the directory path to where the text files have been saved. However,  I did not understand comment about 'filtering. txt/cls files as you need'

Thank you for your help and quick reply.

Comment: The directory you are referring to might contain multiple types of files. If you are intending to take only TXT or CSV file then you need to check file extension of 'obFile'.